# ¿Cómo deshacerse de los valores de NoneType al calcular la similitud del coseno?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Intenté crear la similitud del coseno entre dos columnas de un marco de datos con `spatial.distance.cosine` en otra columna usando estas dos funciones:

```
def cosine_sim(x):
    li = []
    for item in x["sent_emb"]:
        li.append(spatial.distance.cosine(item,x["quest_emb"][0]))
    return li

def predictions(train):

    train["cosine_sim"] = train.apply(cosine_sim, axis = 1)
```

Las dos columnas se ven así:

```
    sent_emb                                            quest_emb
0   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.01491953, 0.021973763, 0.021364095, 0.0393...
1   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.04444952, 0.028005758, 0.030357722, 0.0375...
2   [[0.030376578, 0.044331014, 0.081356354, 0.062...   [[0.03949683, 0.04509903, 0.018089347, 0.07667...
   ...
```

Sin embargo, obtuve un `TypeError`, parece que algunos valores son`NoneType` y `float`. ¿Sabes cómo puedo filtrar los datos de este tipo para configurarlo en cero o algo que no me impida aplicar mis funciones?

El error completa esta:

```
TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 473')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-af28fc11a9d3> in <module>()
----> 1 predicted = predictions(train)

<ipython-input-22-1699cf33d87c> in predictions(train)
      1 def predictions(train):
      2 
----> 3     train["cosine_sim"] = train.apply(cosine_sim, axis = 1)
      4     train["diff"] = (train["quest_emb"] - train["sent_emb"])**2
      5     train["euclidean_dis"] = train["diff"].apply(lambda x: list(np.sum(x, axis = 1)))

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6012                          args=args,
   6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
   6015 
   6016     def applymap(self, func):

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-20-276aa09bc25e> in cosine_sim(x)
      2     li = []
      3     for item in x["sent_emb"]:
----> 4         li.append(spatial.distance.cosine(item,x["quest_emb"][0]))
      5     return li

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py in cosine(u, v, w)
    742     # cosine distance is also referred to as 'uncentered correlation',
    743     #   or 'reflective correlation'
--> 744     return correlation(u, v, w=w, centered=False)
    745 
    746 

~/Documents/programming/mybot/mybotenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py in correlation(u, v, w, centered)
    693         u = u - umu
    694         v = v - vmu
--> 695     uv = np.average(u * v, weights=w)
    696     uu = np.average(np.square(u), weights=w)
    697     vv = np.average(np.square(v), weights=w)

TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'", 'occurred at index 473')
```

#### Mis intentos

Por lo momento intenté :

```
train.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

pero me da :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ bee-YON-say) (born September 4, 1981) is an American singer, songwriter, record producer and actress. Born and raised in Houston, Texas, she performed in
```

Y intenté :

```
np.where(train['sent_emb'].isnull(), 
        None,
        train['sent_emb'].fillna(0).astype(int))
```

pero la ultima linea da el error :

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer un `if (type(item) == NoneType) or (type(item) == Float):` y luego asignarle el valor que quieras?

Comment: @XBoss No hay un método específico para dataframes?

Comment: A mi me suena ese métofo en frameworks como numpy y pandas. ¿Utilizas algunos?

Comment: También puedes utilizar: `if item is None or item in Float:`

Comment: @XBoss Si, acabo de agregar mis intentos fallidos.

Comment: Utilizas Numpy entonces?

Comment: @XBoss Intenté convertir columnas seleccionadas en panda dataframe en Numpy Array con `train.as_matrix(columns=[train["sent_emb","quest_emb"]])` pero me dice que `only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices`

Comment: prueba con `train.fillna(0).astype(int64)`

Comment: Ya he encontrado tu problema, tu código: `.fillna(0).astype(int)` es correcto, pero se lo aplicas a todo el dataframe, debes aplicárselo solo a la columna de números, porque veo que en tu dataframe tienes columnas con números y columnas con cadenas de texto.

Comment: Creo que es: `train["sent_emb"].fillna(0).astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

Como [reportado por Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/869098/284043), para evitar None, puedo hacer eso:

```
def cosine_sim(x):
    li = []

    for item in x["sent_emb"]:
        sent_emb = item if item is not None else 0
        quest_emb = x["quest_emb"][0] if x["quest_emb"][0] is not None else 0
        li.append(spatial.distance.cosine(sent_emb, quest_emb))
    return li
```

Pero eso me lleva a este nuevo error y no sé si se tiene en cuenta los `float`.